# Close all open forms (WM 6.5/VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

Is it possible to close all the open forms in a Windows Mobile 6.5 project using VB.NET?
I found some approaches for a desktop solution, something like:

```
For Each f As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
    f.Close()
Next
```

...which seems not possible in WM6.5?
Any idea or approach to do this is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just call Application.Exit?

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your answer. That would indeed be an idea, but I later on want to let the main form (and maybe some others) still opened. That's the reason I would rather want an approach like in the OP.

Comment: Clearly you asked the wrong question, not sure what the point might be.  If you lose track of all your open forms on a mobile app then you are doing it wrong.  Just storing them in a List and removing them again with the FormClosed event is a simple approach.

Comment: @HansPassant I could have formulated my question better, you are right. But no need to accuse me of doing things "wrong" or "right". Even without showing you some code of mine, I know that there is a lot of room for improvement, there always is, right?

Comment: Yeah, you need to create or use a framework that tracks the open forms for you.  In a mobile app the number should be small, and the task should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 3):

### Close all forms except the one where this code is

```
            For i = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
                Dim form As Form = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms(i)
                form.Close()
            Next i
```

'Sorry for my poor english

Comment: this guy is a hero ^^^